# Azure App Service PHP Laravel CSS not loaded

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have facing problem on running PHP Laravel on Azure App Service with Windows environment.
I have follow this tutorial on my current laravel app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-windows

I have set the virtual path into public:
[image]

While the app is running functionally, but the css and image are not loaded. The images and css are all in public folder.

[image]

Anyone has suggestion on web.config or event htaccess that I need to edit?

Thank You

Comment: Why you append  `\public` after Physical path ？

Comment: how's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to expose some static files under a physical path: `site\wwwroot\public` to the public, please config your virtual directory as below:

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you access this setting?

Comment: @JhourladEstrella, just see this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#map-a-url-path-to-a-directory